# Error after Detecting Rails Configuration on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

My rails app is working locally, however, I'm running into issues upon deploying to Heroku. It appears it's precompiling fine, but I get a stack of errors here:

```html
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
remote:        Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
remote:        Asset precompilation completed (1.79s)
remote:        Cleaning assets
remote:        Running: rake assets:clean
remote: -----> Detecting rails configuration
remote:        $ rails runner "begin; puts %Q{heroku.detecting.config.for.assets.compile=#{Rails.application.config.try(:assets).try(:compile)}}; rescue => e; puts e; puts e.backtrace; end; begin; puts %Q{heroku.detecting.config.for.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header=#{Rails.application.config.try(:action_dispatch).try(:x_sendfile_header)}}; rescue => e; puts e; puts e.backtrace; end; begin; puts %Q{heroku.detecting.config.for.active_storage.service=#{Rails.application.config.try(:active_storage).try(:service)}}; rescue => e; puts e; puts e.backtrace; end;"
remote:        /tmp/build_e5c8ea775fe1792a905edb1b8e4870ab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:206:in `rescue in _decrypt': ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage (ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage)
remote:         from /tmp/build_e5c8ea775fe1792a905edb1b8e4870ab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:183:in `_decrypt'
remote:         from /tmp/build_e5c8ea775fe1792a905edb1b8e4870ab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:157:in `decrypt_and_verify'
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: What guide are you following to deploy Rails to Heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is the result of Heroku missing the master key for decrypting the credentials file. Create a `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` ENV variable., Rails will detect this automatically and use it as your master key for decryption.

For heroku: `$ heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=<your-master-key-here>`

This is a [very nice blog post](https://medium.com/cedarcode/rails-5-2-credentials-9b3324851336) to understand how rails credentials API work

Comment: Yup. I was using SECRET_BASE_KEY instead of RAILS_MASTER_KEY in my config vars. Thanks!